# Using the Microsoft Graph Webhooks

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am looking to implement Microsoft Graph webhooks for streaming notifications in my application.

I went through their documentation and trying to follow the sample available at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/java-spring-webhooks-sample

I have one query related to the pre-requisites for webhooks, it is about the `notificationURL`.

It says the notification URL should be a public URL i.e it should be available over the internet.

As per my requirement, my application cannot have a public URL, is there a way I can implement Microsoft Graph webhooks without having a public URL?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you need to have a public HTTPS endpoint to receive and send HTTP requests - it's a pre-requisite. Alternately you can host this on Microsoft Azure or another service/Azure function as well.

Comment: Thanks @Dev .. Could you just elaborate the "Alternately you can host this on Microsoft Azure or another service/Azure function as well" part? I mean any sample or example link would be very helpful. Also, just to reconfirm, public URL won't be required in this case right??

Comment: Ok let me be clear, (1) pre-requisite - a public HTTPS endpoint to receive and send HTTP requests (2) You can host this on Microsoft Azure or another service. Please find the sample which uses [Azure function with Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoftgraph/webjobs-webhooks-sample/microsoft-graph-webhooks-sample-using-webjobs-sdk/).

Answer (score 0):

Use ngrock tool to create tunnel to hosting your localhost in public domain till the ngrock live.